# D3 - Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am getting the following exception when implemented the example from: http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html

There is any know workaround for this?

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'map'

Thanks!

Comment: Can't really help you without knowing what you're doing.

Comment: Sounds like `data` is an object, rather than an array of objects. Try `console.log(data)` within the callback to check the structure of `data`.